# Trying out gatsby-theme-apollo - server not visible

Tags: gatsby, react-apollo

Having problems getting started
https://github.com/apollographql/gatsby-theme-apollo/tree/master/packages/gatsby-theme-apollo

**STEPS taken:**

```
>     gatsby new atest
>     cd atest
>     npm install gatsby-theme-apollo @apollo/client
>     make new directory: atest/src/gatsby-theme-apollo
>     make new file in directory: client.js
>     copy paste content from instructions without change:

    import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
    import {ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache} from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      link: new HttpLink({
        uri: 'https://api.spacex.land/graphql/',
        fetch
      })
    })
```

in browser: checked that spacex api is up 
terminal: gatsby develop 
browser: Navigate to localhost:8000/___graphql

Queries are available for site  OK However, no spacex queries available.
Any steps missing?
(On ubuntu 18.04 node 12.14.1, gatsby 2.19.7)

Answer (score 0):

NOT A PROBLEM: It is only when connecting serverside graphql that the server shows up along with the rest of the gatsby schemas, so this behaviour is as expected. The client queries are handled separately - see https://github.com/jlengstorf/gatsby-with-apollo and associated You Tube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNUg1jpj9T0 from the middle for a good description.